# Why Does PyTorch Use So Much GPU Memory to Store Tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I made a simple test using PyTorch which involves measuring the current GPU memory use, creating a tensor of a certain size, moving it to the GPU, and measuring the GPU memory again. According to my calculation, around 6.5k bytes were required to store each element of the tensor! Here is the break down:

1. GPU memory use before creating the tensor as shown by `nvidia-smi`: 384 MiB.
2. Create a tensor with 100,000 random elements:

```py
a = torch.rand(100000)
```

3. Transfer the tensor to the GPU:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda')
b = a.to(device)
```

4. GPU memory use after the transfer: 1020 MiB
5. Calculate memory change per one element of the tensor

```py
(1020-384)*1024*1024/len(b)
# Answer is 6668.94336
```

This is weird, to say the least. Why would 6.5 KiB of GPU memory be required to store a single `float32` element?

---

**UPDATE**: Following Robert Crovella's suggestion in the comment, I created another tensor `c` and then moved it to the CUDA device on `d`. The GPU memory usage didn't increase. So, it seems that PyTorch or CUDA requires some 636 MiB for bootstrapping. Why is that? What is this memory used for? It seems a lot to me!

Comment: after creating the first tensor `a` and moving it to the device on `b`, take your GPU memory use measurement.  Then create another tensor `c` and move to the device on `d`.  Then take another measurement.  Use the difference between those 2 measurements.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion. This is a bit strange. Why would PyTorch or CUDA require some 636 MiB for bootstrapping?

Comment: It's normal.  It's like asking why the Windows or Linux operating system requires memory to run.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid comparison. With Windows or Linux, you are talking about a kernel, many drivers, a fully-blown user interface, many applications running in the background, and so on. So, I am failing to understand why all this memory is needed to bootstrap CUDA/PyTorch.

Comment: We can agree to disagree.  There is overhead to set up a GPU for usage by CUDA.  I can't give you a description of the details of it, or explain why it is so large.  Since that is  now what your question appears to be, I won't be able to help further.  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, my question is mainly to understand what that memory is used for, but thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12873) should answer your question to some extent. In short, PyTorch defines a ton of CUDA functions to manipulate tensors (in CUDA terms these are called **kernels**). The kernels have to be stored on GPU, apparently. However, this may be not the only thing that consumes memory, unfortunately I'm not an expert in torch internals.